# ImageButton In UpdatePanel Doesn't Firing [Asp.net]

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-5

i'm have a problem with button clicked in asp.net update panel. Here My Code :

My Aspx Code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            
            <div class="modal fade modal-lg" id="mdlVendor" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mdlVendorLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="mdlVendorLabel">Vendor</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtVendorSearch" CssClass="form-control me-2" OnClientClick="javascript:return false;"  data-target="#mdlVendor" OnTextChanged="txtVendorSearch_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvVendor" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="gvVendor_RowCommand">
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEmptyData" Text="No Data Found"></asp:Label>
                                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor Id">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="VendorID" Text='<%# Eval("VendorID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor Name">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="VendorName" Text='<%# Eval("VendorName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/img/add.png" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" CommandName="SelectDataVendor" ToolTip="Select Data Vendor"/>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My Aspx.cs Code :

```
protected void gvVendor_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("SelectDataVendor"))
            {
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                int index = row.RowIndex;
                GridViewRow clickedRow = gvVendor.Rows[index];

                Label VendorName = (Label)clickedRow.Cells[2].FindControl("VendorName");
                txtVendor.Text = VendorName.Text;

            }
        }
protected void txtVendorSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            string StrSeacrh = txtVendorSearch.Text;

            dt = trxExpenditureCls.GetVendor(StrSeacrh);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gvVendor.DataSource = dt;
                gvVendor.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
                gvVendor.DataSource = dt;
                gvVendor.DataBind();
                gvVendor.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                gvVendor.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                gvVendor.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dt.Columns.Count;
                gvVendor.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found";
                gvVendor.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            }
        }
```

When i'm click imageButton :

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/img/add.png" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" CommandName="SelectDataVendor" ToolTip="Select Data Vendor"/>
```

system doesn't debug into gvVendor_RowCommand. When i make breakpoint in Page_Load, debugger goes into method gvVendor_RowCommand too. But i get a problem, txtVendor doesn't filled after debugger finish.

I'm already try :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPnl2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/img/add.png" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" CommandName="SelectDataVendor" ToolTip="Select Data Vendor" ID="btnAdd"/>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="btnAdd" eventname="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And both

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="btnAdd" eventname="Click" />
```

Or

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger controlid="btnAdd" />
```

None of All fix my problem, even i have tried :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPnl2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddNewData" OnClick="bntAddNewData_Click" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="btnAddNewData" eventname="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Still doesn't fix my problem, is anyone can help me? i'm stuck here. Thanks you before

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I don't think the introduction of a update panel should matter.

On the other hand? I long ago dumped the use of the row command.

Most don't realize that you can drop in a standard asp.net button, or image button.

Just wire up a plane jane click event for the code behind. The beauty of this approach is you don't have to clutter up  bunch of events into the row command.
(VERY little reason to bother or use that).

So, say we drop in a button into the GV.

Now, we can't double click on the button in the designer to auto wire up a event, but you can do this in the markup. Just type in onclick= -- and intel-sense will pop this up:

[image]

So, choose create new event.

And now you have this code for the image button click event:

```
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        // get pkID
        int PKID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        Debug.Print("PK ID = " + PKID);
        Debug.Print("Row index click = " + gRow.RowIndex);

        Label VendorName = (Label)gRow.FindControl("VendorName");
        txtVendor.Text = VendorName.Text;

    }
```

So you don't have to use row command. But, you can drop in a plain jane button, or image button - just wire up a plain old regular event. You can pick up the current row as per above, and you off to the races.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but the condition is still the same...  OnClick event on the ImageButton doesn't work

Comment: Remove the Post back trigger - that's not required. Late but I'll take closer look tomorrow. Remove commandname also

Comment: I'm replace My ImageButton Code to `<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAddData" ImageUrl="~/img/add.png" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" ToolTip="Select Data Vendor" OnClick="btnAddData_Click"/>` but still the image button doesn't firing

Comment: Remove/comment the update panel in the form and try it with the OnClientClick with simple javascript alert . some times update panel will not show the Error.

Comment: @SunderSakthivel i'm using UpdatePanel for keep Modal bootstrap appear when button in modal form clicked / when Post back is triggered